# BeautifulSoup, getting more returns than expected with regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup, I have the following line:

```
dimensions = SOUP.select(".specs__title > h4", text=re.compile(r'Dimensions'))
```

However, it's returning more than just the tags that have a text of 'Dimensions' as shown in these results:

```
[<h4>Dimensions</h4>, <h4>Details</h4>, <h4>Warranty / Certifications</h4>]
```

Am I using the regex incorrectly with the way SOUP works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` interface doesn't have a `text` keyword. Before we go further, the following is assuming you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7+.

If you'd like to filter by text, you might be able to do something like this:

```
dimensions = SOUP.select(".specs__title > h4:contains(Dimensions)")
```

More information on the `:contains()` pseudo-class implementation is available here: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#:contains.

EDIT: To clarify, there is no way to incorporate regex directly into a `select` call currently. You would have to filter the elements after the fact to use regex. In the future there may be a way to use regex via some custom pseudo-class, but currently there is no such feature available in Soup Sieve (Beautiful Soup's select implementation in 4.7+).

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! And thank you for the reference to the :contains() docs as well!

Comment: No problem. I'm the author/maintainer of Soup Sieve, so just letting people know what it can do :).